# how to return only one query result from two query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The sql queries that I currently have are as follow. I have tried some of the joint queries but they didn't work.

```
Select file_path
from images
where image_id In (
  Select image_id
  from temp_images
  where object_uid IN (
    Select  object_uid
    from object_table
    where object_status = 2 and object_place like "%some_keyword%"))`


Select object_uid, object_utitle
from object_table
where object_status = 2 and object_place like "%some_keyword%"`
```

There may be many rows returned by both queries. I would like to return both file_path and object_uid like this.

-Image_id | Object_uid | Object_utitle

-img1     | obj1       | Title 1

-img2     | obj2       | Title 2

-img2     | obj2       | Title 3

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: How many rows are returned by both queries? Is it always one each?

Comment: Are you looking for 1 record that contains data from each or seperate records?

Comment: Sorry for my english. There may be many rows returned by both queries. But I would like to return like these.

Image_id | Object_uid | Object_utitle

img1     | obj1       | Title 1
img2     | obj2       | Title 2
img2     | obj2       | Title 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select a.file_path, b.object_uid, b.object_utitle
from images a, (Select  object_uid, object_utitle
    from object_table
    where object_status = 2 and object_place like "%some_keyword%") b
where image_id In (
  Select image_id
  from temp_images
  where object_uid IN (b.object_uid) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select object_uid, object_utitle from object_table where object_status = 2 and object_place like "%some_keyword%" LIMIT 0,1
```

It will select just one entry, add `ORDER BY DESC/ASC` depending what would you like to show.

Comment: There may be many rows returned by both queries. I would like to return both file_path and object_uid like this.

-Image_id | Object_uid | Object_utitle

-img1 | obj1 | Title 1

-img2 | obj2 | Title 2

-img2 | obj2 | Title 3

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: If there is more then 1 entry that you want to return, then don't put limit but create a loop to print out all the information needed

Answer (score 0):

You can just join the tables.

```
   Select i.Image_id , i.file_path , o.object_uid  
   FROM images i
   INNER JOIN temp_images t ON t.image_id = i.image_id
   INNER JOIN object_table o ON o.object_uid = t.object_uid
   WHERE object_status = 2 and object_place like "%some_keyword%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple inner joins, you should try something like that:

```
SELECT imgs.image_id, obj.object_uid, obj.object_utitle
    FROM images AS imgs
INNER JOIN temp_images AS tmp_imgs
    ON tmp_imgs.image_id = imgs.image_id
INNER JOIN object_table AS obj
    ON tmp_imgs.object_uid = obj.object_uid
WHERE obj.object_status = 2
    AND obj.object_place LIKE "%some_keyword%"
```